# c++ Derived class changing a base class pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, dynamic-cast

I have a `user class` that has a member pointer to a `data class`. But I want to implement a `derivedUser` that extends `user`, but it also needs to have additional data which is stored in a `derivedData class`, it would look something like this:

```
class Data {
    /*...the stored data...*/
}

class DerivedData : public Data {
    /*...the additional data...*/
}

class User {

    public:
        /*...some methods that use dp...*/

    protected:
         Data* dp;
}


class DerivedUser : public User {

    public:
        /*...even more methods that use ddp...*/

    protected:
         DerivedData* ddp;
}
```

But here is the problem: With the way I've set it up the `DerivedUser class` would store two pointers of different types pointing to the same object, which is not optimal. The `DerivedUser` should only store one pointer, and it should know that it is of the type `DerivedData` and fail if it is given the wrong type of data. And the question is: how do I implement this?

Ive tried:

```
class DerivedUser : public User {

    public:
        /*...even more methods that use ddp...*/

    protected:
        DerivedData* ddp = dynamic_cast<DerivedData*>(dp);
}
```

Comment: Aren't there constructors that initialize `private`/`protected` field of those classes? So, why can't you make a constructor, that only accepts a `Data` instance of the appropriate type, and use that for initialization of the fields?

Comment: Why point to derived classes at all? Use virtual functions and only point to the base if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a method `DerivedData* GetData()` in the DerivedUser class

`DerivedData* GetData()
{
  return static_cast<DerivedData>(dp);
}`

You can make sure `dp` is a `DerivedData*` if the constructor of DerivedUser looks like this:

`DerivedUser(DerivedData* d):User(d){}`

Here is the full code:

```
class Data {
    /*...the stored data...*/
}

class DerivedData : public Data {
    /*...the additional data...*/
}

class User {

    public:
        User(Data* d):dp(d){}
        /*...some methods that use dp...*/

    protected:
        Data* dp;
}

class DerivedUser : public User {

    public:
        DerivedUser(DerivedData* d):User(d){}
        /*...even more methods that use ddp...*/

    protected:
        DerivedData* GetData(void)
        {
            return static_cast<DerivedData*>(dp);
        };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I see that you want DerivedUser to have DerivedData in its constructor.

Because of polymorphism a parent class can references it child class. So this is legal:

```
Data* dp = new DerivedData();
```

Here is the solution you are looking for:

```
class User {

public:
    /*...some methods that use dp...*/

    User(Data* dp){
        this->dp = dp;
    }

protected:
    Data* dp;
};

class DerivedUser : public User {

public:
    /*...even more methods that use ddp...*/

    DerivedUser(DerivedData *dp) : User(dp) {

    }
};
```

Now, DerivedUser points to your DerivedData class

Here:

```
int main(){

    DerivedData* dp = new DerivedData();

    DerivedUser* user = new DerivedUser(dp);


    return 0;
}
```